# Structured to do list with subheaders like "Today", "Friday", "Next Week", "March" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I want to make a to do list in JavaScript which looks something like this:

- NO DEADLINE
- Be awesome
- Live life
- TODAY
- Walk the dog
- Buy food
- Work out
- THIS WEEK
- Lorem
- Ipsum
- Dolor
- NEXT WEEK
- Dolor
- Ipsum

Basically it needs to be dynamic so I don't want the subheaders to be the same all the time.

If there's more than, say, 2 tasks due "Tomorrow" I want there to be a header saying "Tomorrow", if there's 5 tasks due spread out this week I want it to say "This Week" instead.

If there's not a lot of things going on "Next Week", but tasks are spread out throughout the next month, I want it to say "Next Month" instead etc.

So I'll have a JSON object with tasks, something like this:

```
var tasks =
[
  { 
     due: '2017-05-01-17:00',
     task: 'Do something',
  }, 
  { 
     due: '2017-22-01-17:00',
     task: 'Do something else',
  }

  // ...
]
```

And I'd like some kind of algorithm to sort it into a dynamic to do list.

Comment: So what did you try to make this happen?

Comment: I think you will have to make define algorithm yourself based on your preferences. It might make it easy to see with a switch statement and have a hierarchy of what tabs are displayed. I would start with the general, Today, Tomorrow, This Week, Next Month, and work from there to refine it.

Answer (score 0):

Trouble is with overlapping. Tasks for today are also tasks for "this week" and "this month" so if you do a simple count you will get unpredictable results. I.e. you have 5 tasks today and 1 in 2 days. Counter for "this week" will return 6 but if you decide to use "today" header, actual number of tasks left for next header will be 1.

If possible, I'd try to change query to DB to calculate flags for each task in database. So each task would also have simple Boolean tags: today, tomorrow, this week, next week, this month... If this is complex to do in your DB you can also transform original array to this in JavaScript.

Then, make a loop going from "today" to "next month" like:

1. count tasks having "today" flag and if more than minimum output this header in headers collection.
2. count tasks having "this week" flag set but exclude those that have flag "today" if "today" is already in collection (otherwise do not exclude them). If count is above your minimum, add this header to collection.

... repeat.